# To find Basis and kernel of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A:$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 5 & 13 \\ -2 & -1 & -4 \end{pmatrix}

My textbook has reduced it to RREF to find kernel and dimension of it. To find the basis for image, they have taken $A^{T}$ and then reduce it to RREF. I don't understand why this has been done; this is my main point of frustration.

Also, let me know if there are any alternative ways to find the basis for the image. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the RREF, you can pick the columns of $A$ corresponding to the pivot columns of the RREF.

If you want a simplified basis, you cannot use the RREF of $A$, as row operations will change the column space. Instead, your book does column operations on $A$ (row operation on $A^T$) to eliminate the columns of $A$ down to echelon form.

Comment: Thanks .But can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers don't answer your question about finding the kernel.

The question about the basis has been well answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1037452/340888

Recall that $\ker(T) =  \{ T(p) = \textbf0_c : p \in domain(T)\}$, where $0_c$ is the zero vector of the codomain.

That is, the kernel of the matrix contains all the vectors $(x, y, z)^T$ such that:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 5 & 13 \\ -2 & -1 & -4 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

The matrix is not invertible since:

$\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 5 & 13 \\ -2 & -1 & -4 \end{pmatrix}=0$

Thus, the only solution is the trivial solution and $ker(T)=\{\textbf0_d\}$ where $0_d$ is the zero vector in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicates, we can find both the kernel and the image of a transformation using the rref of $A$ directly.

For your example, [row reducing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row%20reduce%20%7B%7B1%2C2%2C5%7D%2C%7B3%2C5%2C13%7D%2C%7B-2%2C-1%2C-4%7D%7D) the matrix yields
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 5 & 13 \\ -2 & -1 & -4 \end{pmatrix} \to 
\pmatrix{
1&0&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0
}
$$
We have a pivot (a leading "1") in the first and second column.  It follows that the first and second column form a basis of the image.  That is, the set
$$
\left\{ \pmatrix{1\\3\\-2},\pmatrix{2\\5\\-1}\right\}
$$
is a basis of the image of $A$.

Comment: in general, does this works if you had to swap rows to get to the final row echelon matrix?

Comment: i meant swap. i fixed the typo.

Comment: @abel yes. The key is that row-operations preserve the kernel.

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion. i know that the kernel does not change. but what about the pivot columns of $A$ being the basis of he column space of $A.$

Comment: @abel A basis, not the basis.  And the key is that one follows from the other.  There can be pivots in a certain subset of the columns of the row reduced matrix only if the corresponding columns form a basis of the image.

Comment: got it. what matters is $Ax = 0$ iff $Ux = 0$ where $EPA = U,$ with $E$ lower triangular, $P$ permutation and $U$ in row echelon form.

Comment: So that's why you're wary about row switching.  Yes, the key is that it's all matrix multiplication on the left by an invertible matrix.